# mute audio if the volume *exceeds* a threshold

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, command-line, sox

So, I have spent quite a bit of time looking for the answer but I get the exact opposite (something I already know how to do), namely, the audio *below* a certain threshold can get muted (can be done either with ffmpeg or sox).

What I need is for the command to search my audio for anything that exceeds -18dB and mute all such segments. (The reason for this is because I have a recording where I am playing an electric piano with the audio output being recorded directly through the cable, but I am also recording from two microphones what I am speaking - between my playing. When I am playing the keyboard, the mics pick up a lot of action noise which I want to mute, and that's easy to do because the channel that records my piano input has piano sounds at that point and that corresponds exactly with when I want the audio from my mics to be muted, or at least attenuated.)

Does anyone know if such a feat is possible?
If it cannot be done with just one command, that's fine I'll try anything.

Comment: What you're looking for is commonly called a "gate".  https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#agate

Comment: @Brad Thanks for this. I am trying it out but still only getting the same results as before: i.e. the softs are getting muted, while the louds remain, but I am sure it's just the matter of me finding the right parameters for agate.

Comment: @Brad So, after looking at it closely, I don't actually see where it mentions that it is able to attenuate the loud signal. It says "A gate is mainly used to reduce lower parts of a signal. This kind of signal processing reduces disturbing noise between useful signals." It doesn't actually says about reducing the "higher parts" of a signal and none of the options seem to reverse the behavior.

Comment: So, you have 2 channels... one microphone, one keyboard, and when there is signal on the keyboard you want to mute the microphone?  Hmm, off hand I don't know if any of the utilities in FFmpeg support this sort of sidechaining.

Comment: @Brad Actually, it's slightly simpler than that for me - *both channels can* be muted, because I am simultaneously recording the keyboard signal (which I want to keep) to another stream (file). So, what I want is for the function to go through my signal with ch 1=voice+noise and ch2=keyboard signal, find the "loud bits" (where ch2 "exceeds" -18dB) and just mute both channels during those bits. I can then grab the processed ch1 and mix it with my other (untouched) keyboard signal file.